# Nextjs can't find any page - 404 This page could not be found

Tags: next.js

When running my app with `next dev -p 3001` it results in a 404 page cannot be found error.

My `_app.tsx`:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  console.log('pageProps: ', pageProps)
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

pageProps returns `{statusCode: 400}`

This is my file setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my `getStaticProps()` was returning undefined due to an undefined variable before it could return props to the page component.

Checking all `getStaticProps()` functions resolved this issue